# People starting bounty's less trustworthy?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I was thinking about starting a bounty for [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac), but I was wondering about the following:

When you start a bounty, you are giving away your reputation.

This is what [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) says about reputation:

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you

So if you create a bounty, that means you are less trustworthy?

Can someone explain?

Comment: Emphasis on the "rough."

Comment: Nah, you're awesome because you're putting your reputation on the line.... It's a rough measurement. But don't get too hung up on that statement.

Comment: The bounty system is part of the _gamification_ of the site, but it's not a very good measure of someone's contribution level. There are some channels `(cough)Android(cough)` where users just ask a large number of poor-quality questions that result in apparently good reputation totals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have 2k rep and keep offering 100 point bounties without answering any questions, then yes, you will look less reputable.  And we want that - use bounties when you need them, don't view your rep as simple currency for throwing more bounties around.

So yes, you are correct, and this should damper the rate at which you post bounties.  But dropping from 2200 to 2100 isn't going to make the community view you with ire.

Comment: Dropping from 2200 to 2100 may be not look like a very big difference, but I think that dropping from (for example) 112 to 12 is a different story. But thanks ;)

Comment: @com.BOY yeah I wouldn't recommend that.  And that is how bounties work, you need to be able to afford them with respect to how you want your rep, privileges, etc. impacted.

Answer (score 7):

Reputation is more of a measurement of veterancy and how helpful you are. It doesn't make you any less expert of trustworthy to give away a bounty.

It's not like reputation is an absolute measurement anyway, I've seen 1 rep users answering much better than certain 50k ones.

Comment: I liked your example 1 vs 50k.

Comment: But when they do, they turn into 10k ones soon enough :).

Comment: @Linuxios: Sadly, the 50k ones don't go away.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: How true ;).